# foreach with in a foreach php

Tags: php, magento, loops, foreach

Hi i have a script in which there is a `foreach` within a `foreach`. The *first* `foreach` is used for id which is unique, but the second `foreach` used is for related images of a product which should loop according to the number of images. However, it restricts me to fetch only one related image, how can i get all related images?

```
$i=0;
foreach ($collection as $product_all) { 
    //echo $product_all->getId().'<br/>';
    if($i==10) break;  
    $id = $product_all->getId();        
    $neew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);         
    //echo'<pre>';
        echo 'active products id ===='.$neew ->getId().'<br/>';  
        echo 'active products name ===='.$neew->getname().'<br/>';    
        echo 'active products style_ideas ===='.$neew->getstyle_ideas().'<br/>';  
        echo 'active products size and fit ===='.$neew->getsize_fit().'<br/>';  
        echo 'active products short description ===='.$neew->getshort_description().'<br/>';  
        echo 'active products  description ===='.$neew->getdescription().'<br/>';  
        //print_r($neew); 
        if (count($neew->getMediaGalleryImages()) > 0){
            $i = 0 ;
            $j = 0 ;
            foreach ($neew->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image){
                  $relative_image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($neew->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(2000);
                  $relative_image1 = str_replace('/webApps/migration/productapi/new/','/',$relative_image);
                  //echo 'relative_image => '.$relative_image1.'<br/>';
                  $relative_image_save = $relative_image1 ;
                  $relative_image_save1 = explode('/', $relative_image_save);//explode / to get only image name
                  $end1 = end($relative_image_save1);
                  $relative_image3 = $end1;
                  //$handle1 = fopen( $relative_image3, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '. $relative_image);
                  $path12 = '/mnt/aviesta/development/webApps/migration/productapi/new/'.'sku-'.$neew->getsku().'_' .$i++.'.jpg';
                  copy($relative_image_save, $path12);
                  echo 'relative image with sku path_'.$j++.' ====>'.$path12.'<br/><br/>'; 
               }
           }
      $i++;
}
```

Comment: What does `$neew->getMediaGalleryImages()` return?

Comment: Are you sure your MediaGalleryImages collection's size is not 1? What is the value of count($neew->getMediaGalleryImages() in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

From  your code i think the problem can be solved by initializing an array before your 2nd foreach loop , and storing the images in that array can help you out in fetching all the images....This is what i understood from your question. If this is correct.., than the below code may work....

```
foreach()
{
    //Your code....
     $image_list = array();
     $i = 0;
     foreach()
      {
        // Your usual code 
       $image_list[$i] = your_image;
       //storing images one-by-one in your variable..
       $i++;
       }
}
```

You can later return the variable or just print_r(); to get the output

Answer (score 0):

i think i have post the question in little **hurry**, the script works **fine** , for the initial products there was a single images for the products but for the newer products there are multiple images and the script works fine , **thanks** to all of **you** to respond the post .....